# file-sharing vs. file sharing?

Tags: word-usage, difference

I wanted to write the sentence below:

"Do you use file sharing services?"

Should I write "file-sharing" instead of "file sharing"? Does it matter? I want to use "file sharing" as an adjective.

The only reference I found comes from [Macmillan Dictionary.](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/file-sharing) Do they use "-" between words because it's a noun? How would they write "file sharing" as an adjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Punctuation is used to improve clarity. In this case the words "file-sharing" function as a single modifier. It helps to write the hyphen.

Consider the example "a man-eating lion"  and "a man eating lion" (the second literally means a person who is consuming lion meat)